# Why is this instance variable being assigned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was reading an article about ruby service objects at:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/service-objects-with-rails-using-aldous--cms-23689

I'm not understanding why @user_data_hash is being assigned a value.  It is not being used anywhere in the code.  I've seen few other examples doing same thing in other articles I've read.  What is the need of assigning to this instance variable?

```
class CreateUserService < Aldous::Service
  attr_reader :user_data_hash

  def initialize(user_data_hash)
    @user_data_hash = user_data_hash
  end

  def default_result_data
    {user: nil}
  end

  def perform
    user = User.new(user_data_hash)

    if user.save
      Result::Success.new(user: user)
    else
      Result::Failure.new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Without reading the docs too much, it looks like it's just an example of data that might be passed in from a user's cookies when they login.

Answer (score 2):

`@user_data_hash` is used, because

```
attr_reader :user_data_hash
```

is a macro for:

```
def user_data_hash
  @user_data_hash
end
```

That means: This line `user = User.new(user_data_hash)` in the `perform` method will read the hash assigned to `@user_data_hash`:

Comment: ahhh that makes sense.  Not requiring parenthesis in ruby with user_data_hash as an argument confused me.  I was thinking the correct way to write this would be User.new(@user_data_hash).

Comment: It is considered best practive not to call instance variables directly, but through a getter. That makes it much easier to refactor later on. Therefore `User.new(@user_data_hash)` is not the correct way, but another way.

Answer (score 1):

`attr_reader` defines a method called `user_data_hash`, which returns `@user_data_hash`. So it is being used whenever you call `user_data_hash`.